# Android Pre-Existing/External Database Security Concerns

Tags: android, database, sqlite, file, security

I have a SQLite DB that I include with the APK. DB is under Assets folder and is copied over to a folder on internal storage.

Everything works fine, however I have security concerns regarding the DB.

More specifically someone copying and opening my DB file.

How would one go about securing the DB file?

Comment: Don't put the "DB file" on the user's device.

Answer (score 1):

You could encrypt the database if you wanted to, but then you would need to include a key in your program to decrypt it. Here is one easy to use product [SQLCipher](https://www.zetetic.net/sqlcipher/sqlcipher-for-android/).

At the end of the day, the best you can do is make it harder for the DB to copied off the phone and read.

Comment: Will I have to deal with encrypting & decrypting upon every query or does it function as a wrapper of some sort?

Comment: SQLCipher functions as a wrapper that does all that work for you. So your code really doesn't have to change at all (aside from providing the the decryption key to open the DB)

Comment: Great, will try this out.